# Labels in DateListPlot not visible

Tags: plotting, labeling, options, date-and-time

The problem: I combine two lists in one [`DateListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot.html). The first list has labels. **When I combine both in one `DateListPlot`, some of the labels are not visible.**

```
data = {
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 01}], 1,"label1"}, 
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 02}], 2, "label2"}, 
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 03}], 3,"label3"},  
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 04}], 4,"label4"}, 
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 05}], 5,"label5"},  
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 06}], 6,"label6"}, 
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 07}], 7,"label7"},  
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 08}], 8,"label8"}, 
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 09}], 9,"label9"},  
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 10}], 10,"label10"}, 
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 11}], 11,"label11"},  
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 12}], 12, "label12"}
};
```

When I visualise data like:

```
graf1 = DateListPlot[Rule[data[[All, {1, 2}]], data[[All, 3]]]
  , PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}
  , LabelingFunction -> Right
  , Joined -> False
  ]
```

[image]

The other datasets look like:

```
data1 = { 
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 01}], 10},  
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 02}], 1},  
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 03}], 9},  
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 04}], 2},  
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 05}], 8},  
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 06}], 3},  
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 07}], 9},  
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 08}], 8},  
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 09}], 6},  
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 10}], 5},  
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 11}], 7},  
 {DateObject[{2021, 01, 12}], 4} 
};
```

When I combine both datasets in one graph like:

```
graf2 = DateListPlot[{data1[[All, {1, 2}]], 
   Rule[data[[All, {1, 2}]], data[[All, 3]]]}
  , PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}
  , Joined -> {True, False}
  , Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{.75, Automatic}, {5, Automatic}}
  ];
```

Now the output looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the labels 'label1', 'label2', and 'label8' are not visible.

**Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Alternative 1

To have access to options like [`LabelVisibility`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LabelVisibility.html) one option is to use [`Callout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html) explicitly and add the option to each point.

```
DateListPlot[
{
  data1[[All, {1, 2}]],
  Callout[Most[#],Last[#],LabelVisibility->All]&/@data
}
, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}
, Joined -> {True, False}
, PlotRange->{All, All}
, PlotTheme->"Scientific"
]
```

[image]

## Alternative 2

Otherwise, you could use [`SetOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html) to change the default option and use your own code.

```
SetOptions[Callout,LabelVisibility->All];
```

Comment: Good answer. THANKS!!